# converting an script from PHP mysql_insert_id header, location method to PHP session method

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have successfully implemented data transfer attempt from one page to another using PHP mysql_insert_id header, location method. What I did was:

I have validated it (transferring (i.e. form action) the form to the same page), I have saved it in database, and now I m trying to display the data on another page.

page1 (where original form is located)

```
$id =  mysql_insert_id();
header('Location: page2.php?id='.$id);
```

and in page2

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM form1 WHERE id=$id";
{
 // there after display of data
}
```

The problem I faced:

I m getting this link in the title bar

`http://localhost/aaa/page2.php?id=76`

now if I try to change id= 56 or 45 or any other it is changing displayed data to that id.. so any user can change it in address bar and hence will be able to see my db values..

I thought of encoding it in first place, then at second place I thought of changing it to sessions instead.

so I searched a lot on google to set it as session and I tried this

```
<?php 
// Starting the session 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) //and is this use of id correct?
{ // then what?
}
```

thanks guys for your help

Comment: Sessions can also be modified, still being not secure. But the question is: why dont you want to allow your users to access other content by changing the ID? Is it private only for some users?

Comment: You're looking for a proper **authentication** and **permission** system, not for hiding the id in various ways. If a user is not allowed to see something, *reject* the request.

Comment: @Steve this data is related to a form.. the values of form I m saving to db and it is to be paid at a later stage, so if users change the id so the values will change and users may pay less and get more, also that will be tedious for me to cross check with paypal

Comment: Passing variables from a form using `GET` doesn't make sense in this case... Anyway, form inputs can also be modified using `POST`... if you are talking about money then you should take a look at some secure procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explain what you are exactly trying to do ? so that we can give suggestion . Though below code will work fine. But i  think no use of it.Use session_start before using the session.

Page 1:

```
$id =  mysql_insert_id();
$_SESSION['last_id'] = $id;
header('Location: page2.php');
```

Page 2:
     $id = $_SESSION['last_id'];

```
 $query  = "SELECT * FROM form1 WHERE id=$id";
  {
// there after display of data
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

page1.php:

```
<form action="post" action="page2.php">
       <input name="name" type="hidden" value="<?=mysql_insert_id();?>"></input>
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
  $id = $_POST['name'];
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM form1 WHERE id=$id";
?>
```